# How to get a View view2 below a View view1, but overlapping it?

Tags: android, layout

I want my layout to have a `background` view below a `header` view, but with the `header` view overlapping the `background` view by a few pixels because it has some transparency.

I know the z-order is determined on the order of the views in the XML file, so I put the `header` below the `background`, with `android:layout_above="@id/background"` attribute.

But since I set both dimensions of the `background` to `match_parent`, the `header` is not visible.

How can I achieve what I want?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/background"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_header" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use **FrameLayout** as a parent layout for those views you want to overlap and then arrange them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
    android:background="#80ff0000" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#8000ff00" >
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In that case the background overlap the header. I want it the other way round.